# How to detect parallelograms from the detected edge points in python

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, edge-detection, hough-transform

I am reading an image and trying to detect parallelogram in the image. I have created an array which contains edge points(local peaks) using Hough Transform
(p = x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta)). I got around 2300 edge points(X,Y) and I am not sure how to get/extract parallelogram from it. Out of 2300 edge points, some of the edge points are of circular shape, the triangular shape including parallelogram.

If I start considering edge-points(X,Y) as it is then it will not work as they are not only vertices of parallelogram and edge points are in big number(2300 points).

[EDIT1]

I have stored the edge point in **test_img** and it contains the pixel value.
test_img[point.getX(), point.getY()] = 255

test_img.size = 2343

After plotting above test_image "plt.imshow(test_img, cmap="gray")" I am getting image as below

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: We'd really need some code and format/shape of your inputs/outputs to even start thinking about this.  Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for feedback and I have updated

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: This code was written before OP gave any example. It should work with a point cloud. It cannot find "almost-parallelograms", though.**

A naive approach would be to calculate `(dx, dy)` for every pair of points and save them in a dict. The values of the dict is a list of points pairs. If there is more than 1 pair, every combination of pairs will form a parallelogram.

It's not efficient (`O(n**2)`) but still doable with 2300 points. It's also much more efficient than simply testing every 4-tuple of points.

Here's a quick and dirty implementation:

```
from random import randint, random
from collections import defaultdict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

# N = 2300
# width = 3000
# height = 2000
N = 180
width = 3000
height = 2000
points = [(randint(0, width), randint(0, height)) for _ in range(N)]
points = list(set(points))  # unique points
n = len(points)

plt.scatter(*zip(*points), linewidth=0.001)

vectors = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(n):
    x1, y1 = points[i]
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        x2, y2 = points[j]
        vectors[(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)].append((i, j))

ax = plt.gca()
for vector, pairs in vectors.items():
    if len(pairs) > 1:
        # TODO: Consider every combination if len(pairs) > 2
        a, b, c, d = points[pairs[0][0]], points[pairs[0][1]], points[pairs[1][1]], points[pairs[1][0]]
        ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(xy=[a, b, c, d], fill=False, color=[random(), random(), random()]))

plt.show()
```

Here's the output with 180 points in a 3000 * 2000 grid:

[image]

With 2300 points, you might find a lot of parallelograms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to get/extract parallelogram in above image.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have neat edges, you could try to apply [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to extract straight line edges:

1. Pick a random point belonging to an edge plus its `N` neighbors and put it into a list `L`. Adjust the procedure of finding neighbors to deal with small gaps.
2. Calculate a line that will fit the data in `L`. Keep track of the line parameters (angle, offset and MSE).
3. Keep adding batches of neighbors and recalculating the linear model until MSE starts to rise.
4. You probably found a line segment! Does it have MSE close to zero, is it long enough? If yes, store the estimated parameters of the line somewhere.
5. Exclude pixels from `L` from the picture.
6. Go to #1.

After you've collected the segments, it should be pretty trivial to find something resembling parallelograms.

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky to get fairly clean and continuous edges.

You can segment them in line segments by the Douglas-Peucker procedure with a suitable straightness tolerance. Keep the segments that are long enough*.

You can also try to fill the gap bewteen close and well aligned segments, as well as reconstruct the broken corners (*then you filter on length only after reconstruction).

If all goes well, you should be able to obtain a description like below, and from this infer the quadrilaterals by analysis of the edge/corner graph. (Mind the parasitic corners at the overlap of the shapes.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to find parallelogram like this